# Excel - Sum values based on strings in separate cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with a long list of names.  The names appear multiple times each in their own row.  I would like to evaluate a cell in each row that corresponds to a name and sum it to only one cell.

```
Name  Value  Sum
John    1     
John    0     
John    1     2
Mike    1     
Mike    0     1
Sarah   1     
Sarah   1      
Sarah   1     3
```

I am not sure of the best and most efficient way of going about this where I can sum all of the values for each specific name into a single value without getting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables, for sure.  This is the epitome of pivot table applications.  When god created pivot tables, he actually used this exact example when he was presenting his idea to the Board of Microsoft.

[Here you go](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html).